# How much are noise-related landing costs for a long-range aircraft at Heathrow?

Tags: landing, noise, cost, egll, aeroacoustics

I am trying to estimate the noise-related costs for a long-range platform aircraft (for example, the Boeing 787) at Heathrow Airport.

I have [found the following table (PDF, page:24)](http://www.boeing.com/commercial/noise/2011HeathrowConditionsofUse.pdf) outlining some costs for night/day landings, but **can anyone tell me which 'chapter' a B787 would considered?** I have looked around extensively, but cannot find any clear explanation on this.

[image: Noise Charges]

Comment: Just FYI. [This PDF](http://www.heathrowairport.com/static/HeathrowAboutUs/Downloads/PDF/Heathrow_%20Airport-2015_airport_charges_decision.pdf) shows the latest charges related to noise categories.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As DeltaLima states, the 787 is a Chapter 4 aircraft.

Directly under the table in your question is another table listing the requirements for each category.

[image: Qualification criteria for noise categories]

So the categories are based on the certified Chapter, and the margin to Chapter 3 standards. Based on these values, the 787 would be categorized as **Chapter 4 Low**.

You can look up aircraft in the NoisedB [here](http://noisedb.stac.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/find.php). Each aircraft is tested for its noise margin. I looked at ID:BOEING_14816, which is a 787-8 powered by a GEnx-1B. It has a noise margin of 30.9, which is compared to the Chapter 4 standard. From looking up a Chapter 3 aircraft like a 747-400, it can be seen that the cumulative reduction between Chapter 3 and 4 is 7.3 EPNdB. I did not see any aircraft that would be above the Chapter 4 Low levels, and most are in the "30 or more" category.

Answer (score 5):

The B787 is a chapter 4 aircraft.

I don't know whether that would be chapter 4 'High', 'Base' or 'Minus'. These qualifications seem to be specifically used at Heathrow. I'd expect the B787 to be in the Base or Minus category since its noise levels are well below the ICAO
Chapter 4 standard.

Comment: do you have a reference for this standard? never heard (no pun intended) of it.

Comment: @Federico References [here](http://www.icao.int/Meetings/Green/Documents/day%201pdf/session%202/2-Dickson.pdf) and [here](http://www.icao.int/environmental-protection/pages/noise.aspx)